# how to get previous and next data on button click from SQlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on QuizActivity and unable to get the Previous question from database when reach on last question then on clicking previous button then first question appears in activity. Need help stuck from last 2 days.Thanks

```
  DATABASE

   public List<NotificationListItem> getNQuestions() {
   List<NotificationListItem> quest = new ArrayList<NotificationListItem>();
   String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME2;
   openToRead();
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            NotificationListItem item = new NotificationListItem();
            item.setqID(cursor.getInt(1));
            item.setAnswer(cursor.getString(2));
            item.setTestID(cursor.getString(3));
            item.setquestions(cursor.getString(4));
            item.setOption1(cursor.getString(5));
            item.setOption2(cursor.getString(6));
            item.setOption3(cursor.getString(7));
            item.setOption4(cursor.getString(8));
            item.setOption5(cursor.getString(9));
            item.setAnscount(cursor.getString(10));
            item.setTc(cursor.getString(11));
            quest.add(item);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return quest;
}

public List<NotificationListItem> getPQuestions() {
    List<NotificationListItem> quest = new ArrayList<NotificationListItem>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME2;
    openToRead();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            NotificationListItem pitem = new NotificationListItem();
            pitem.setqID(cursor.getInt(1));
            pitem.setAnswer(cursor.getString(2));
            pitem.setTestID(cursor.getString(3));
            pitem.setquestions(cursor.getString(4));
            pitem.setOption1(cursor.getString(5));
            pitem.setOption2(cursor.getString(6));
            pitem.setOption3(cursor.getString(7));
            pitem.setOption4(cursor.getString(8));
            pitem.setOption5(cursor.getString(9));
            pitem.setAnscount(cursor.getString(10));
            pitem.setTc(cursor.getString(11));
            quest.add(pitem);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return quest;
}
public int getpreviousid() {
    int previd=0;
    openToRead();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME2;
    Cursor cursor=null;
    cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToPrevious()) {
        previd=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_QID));
    }
        cursor.close();
    return previd;
}


QUIZACTIVITY

NotificationListItem Nitem,Pitem;
List<NotificationListItem> Nquest,Pquest;
int score=0;
int qID=0,anscount,totalchoice,tq,questionid,previd;
QuizTable quizTable;
LinearLayout rc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_activity_b);

    qs = getIntent().getStringExtra("questions");
    tq = Integer.parseInt(qs);
    prevBT.setEnabled(false);
    quizTable = new QuizTable(this);
    quizTable.openToRead();
    quizTable.openToWrite();
    Nquest=quizTable.getNQuestions();
    Pquest=quizTable.getPQuestions();
    lastid=quizTable.getLastId();
    firstid=quizTable.getFirstId();
    previd=quizTable.getpreviousid();
    Nitem=Nquest.get(questionid);
    Pitem=Pquest.get(previd);

    setQuestionView();

    nextBT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(questionid<Integer.parseInt(lastid)){                    
                Nitem=Nquest.get(questionid);
                prevBT.setEnabled(true);
                setQuestionView();      
            }  
            else{  
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivityB.this, TestAnalysisActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }}
    });

    prevBT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(questionid<Integer.parseInt(lastid)){                    
                    Pitem=Pquest.get(previd);
                    questionid=previd;
                    setQuestionView1(); 

            }
            if(questionid==Integer.parseInt(lastid))
            {
                 Pitem=Pquest.get(previd);
                 questionid=previd;
                 setQuestionView1();    
            }
            }
    });
}

private void setQuestionView()
{

    txtQuestion.setText(Nitem.getquestions());

      op1=(Nitem.getOption1());
      op2=(Nitem.getOption2());
      op3=(Nitem.getOption3());
      op4=(Nitem.getOption4());
      op5=(Nitem.getOption5());
      ansc=Nitem.getAnscount();
      tc=(Nitem.getTc());
      questionid=(Nitem.getqID());
      if(questionid==Integer.parseInt(firstid))
        {
            prevBT.setEnabled(false);
        }
      totalchoice=Integer.parseInt(tc);
      anscount=Integer.parseInt(ansc);
      System.out.println("QUESTIONID="+questionid);

      if(anscount==1)
        {
        rc.removeAllViews();
        addRadioButtons();
        }
        else if(anscount>1)
        {
        rc.removeAllViews();
        addCheckButtons();
        }}

private void setQuestionView1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(questionid==Integer.parseInt(firstid))
    {
        prevBT.setEnabled(false);
    }
    txtQuestion.setText(Pitem.getquestions());
      op1=(Pitem.getOption1());
      op2=(Pitem.getOption2());
      op3=(Pitem.getOption3());
      op4=(Pitem.getOption4());
      op5=(Pitem.getOption5());
      ansc=Pitem.getAnscount();
      tc=(Pitem.getTc());
      questionid=(Pitem.getqID());
      totalchoice=Integer.parseInt(tc);
      anscount=Integer.parseInt(ansc);
      System.out.println("PREVIOUSID="+ questionid);

      if(anscount==1)
        {
        rc.removeAllViews();
        addRadioButtons();
        }
        else if(anscount>1)
        {
        rc.removeAllViews();
        addCheckButtons();
        }
    }
```

Comment: fetch all data in arraylist and accordingly fetch prev and next

Comment: I am already using Arraylist but I am getting the Previous id from the previd(), so please help me that how we can solve out this issue with some code modification.

Comment: when everything is in arrylist then no need to db operation in getpreviousid

Comment: for getting previous question the what condition we need to apply how we will compare question id?

Comment: you need to keep track of ur QuestionId

Comment: I am doing without using getprevid(), so it gives error. the questions are unable to fetch . if u please help me by updating my code. then it means alot to me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68197/discussion-between-diva-and-user3876078).

Answer (score 0):

We you press Next it means it is obvious to increment questionID hence :

```
 nextBT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            questionid++; // MISSING IN UR CODE
            if(questionid<Integer.parseInt(lastid)){                    
                Nitem=Nquest.get(questionid);
                prevBT.setEnabled(true);
                setQuestionView();      
            }  
            else{  
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivityB.this, TestAnalysisActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }}
    });
```

Comment: and in previous button the question id need to decrement?

Comment: yup ..just a sample class to undesrtand flow : http://pastie.org/pastes/9813614/text